# Sum() AS var when used in same query is saying the var doesn't exist, cannot see why

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that sums a field AS a var and then uses that var in the same select to do a calculation,but it's not recognizing that var for some reason. I've tried all kinds of different ways of constructing the select, but cannot make it recognize the var!

The var in question here is  the_po_cost. Any help, massively appreciated!

```
SELECT `orders`.`id`, accounts.account_name, orders.status, orders.order_type, DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%d-%m-%Y'), `cost`, SUM(po.po_cost) AS the_po_cost, `total_cost`, (orders.cost - (if null(cc.cc_cost, 0) + if null(the_po_cost, 0))) AS Margin, `users`.`email`
FROM (`orders`)JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`account_id` = `orders`.`account_id`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`account_manager_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `po` ON `po`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cc` ON `cc`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER BY `orders`.`id` desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.

Comment: Hi, ok, i see how i need to do this now, thanks for the clarification @GordonLinoff !!

Answer (score 0):

Need to do that sum in the math section rather than on it's own!

```
SELECT `orders`.`id`, accounts.account_name, orders.status, orders.order_type, DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%d-%m-%Y'), `cost`, `total_cost`, (orders.cost - (if null(cc.cc_cost, 0) + if null(SUM(po.po_cost), 0))) AS Margin, `users`.`email`
FROM (`orders`)JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`account_id` = `orders`.`account_id`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`account_manager_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `po` ON `po`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cc` ON `cc`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER BY `orders`.`id` desc
LIMIT 10
```